java how to store in array using if else
I have a piece of code where I'm setting text based on certain conditions in an Android application. Here's a snippet:
if (fifth < 100 && fifth >= 96.5) 
            fivet.setText("1.00");
        
else if (fifth < 97 && fifth >= 92.5) 
            fivet.setText("1.25");       

else if (fifth < 93 && fifth >= 88.5) 
            fivet.setText("1.50");
        
else if (fifth < 89 && fifth >= 84.5) 
            fivet.setText("1.75");
         
else if (fifth < 85 && fifth >= 81.5) 
            fivet.setText("2.00");
         
else if (fifth < 82 && fifth >= 78.5) 
            fivet.setText("2.25");
        
else if (fifth < 79 && fifth >= 75.5) 
            fivet.setText("2.50");
        
else if (fifth < 76 && fifth >= 72.5) 
            fivet.setText("2.75");
        
else if (fifth < 73 && fifth >= 69.5) 
            fivet.setText("3.00");
        
else if (fifth < 70 && fifth >= 0) 
            fivet.setText("5.00");
        
else
            fivet.setText("NE");

Instead of directly setting the text using 'setText', I want to store these output values in an array. How can I modify this code to achieve that?
Thank you!

To me, long if-statements like this belong in a method. The method would take fifth as input and return a string with the appropriate value. I am not sure why you need an Array here.

You one have one value " fivet.setText(" something");".  What do need or want to do with an array?

Did you even look at the post and asked yourself whether the code is readable like that?

you can use the methods of NavigableMap, simplified example: var map = new TreeMap<Double, String>(Map.of(100.0, "NE", 97.0, "1.00", 93.0, "1.25", ..., Double.NEGATIVE INFINITY, "NE")) and then var text = map.floorEntry(fifth).getValue() (this must obviously be expanded and adapted) Also be aware that double is not a very precise representation of a number

BTW the conditions as posted are confusing (kind of overlapping/repeated), better not repeat the conditions like in: if (x >= 100) return "NE"; else if (x >= 97) return "1.00"; else if (x >= 93) return "1.50"; else if (x >= 89) ... else return "NE"; (incomplete example, must be completed/adapted)

You can simplify, (and imo making it more readable), by adjusting your series of if statements to only check one constraint.  They will continue to fall thru until a condition matches.
In this case the order of the statements is critical and must be either ascending or descending order depending on your condition.
I used print statements so you could verify the logic. To store in an array you would need to pre-allocate the array to hold the return value.  That could be something like:
String[] result = new String[1]; // room for one element
result[0] = checkValue1(fifth);

For a more precise answer you would need to give examples of what you are trying to do.
To compare the two approaches I test them by calling each with the same argument and comparing the returns.  Since I am short circuiting the tests by returning the value immediately, the else construct is not necessary.
Random r= new Random();
int N = 100_000_000;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    double fifth = r.nextDouble(-10, 110);
    String v1 = checkValue1(fifth);
    String v2 = checkValue2(fifth);
    if (!v1.equals(v2)) {
        System.out.printf("Oops:  %s != %s%n", v1, v2);
    }
}

public static String checkValue1(double fifth) {
    if (fifth >= 100 || fifth < 0) {
            return "NE";
    }

    if (fifth >= 96.5)
        return "1.00";

     if (fifth >= 92.5)
        return "1.25";

     if (fifth >= 88.5)
        return "1.50";

     if (fifth >= 84.5)
        return "1.75";

     if (fifth >= 81.5)
        return "2.00";

     if (fifth >= 78.5)
        return "2.25";

     if (fifth >= 75.5)
        return "2.50";

     if (fifth >= 72.5)
        return "2.75";

     if (fifth >= 69.5)
        return "3.00";

     return "5.00";
  
}

public static String checkValue2(double fifth) {
     if (fifth < 100 && fifth >= 96.5)
        return "1.00";

     if (fifth < 97 && fifth >= 92.5)
        return "1.25";

     if (fifth < 93 && fifth >= 88.5)
        return "1.50";

     if (fifth < 89 && fifth >= 84.5)
        return "1.75";

     if (fifth < 85 && fifth >= 81.5)
        return "2.00";

     if (fifth < 82 && fifth >= 78.5)
        return "2.25";

     if (fifth < 79 && fifth >= 75.5)
        return "2.50";

     if (fifth < 76 && fifth >= 72.5)
        return "2.75";

     if (fifth < 73 && fifth >= 69.5)
        return "3.00";

     if (fifth < 70 && fifth >= 0)
        return "5.00";
     
     return "NE";
}


I can store this easily in an arraylist.
ArrayList<String> store = new ArrayList<>();
     
if (fifth < 100 && fifth >= 96.5) 
      store .add("1.00");   
            
else if (fifth < 97 && fifth >= 92.5) 
      store.add("1.25");       
    
else if (fifth < 93 && fifth >= 88.5) 
      store.add("1.50");
    
else if (fifth < 89 && fifth >= 84.5) 
      store.add("1.75");
    
else if (fifth < 85 && fifth >= 81.5) 
      store.add("2.00");
    
else if (fifth < 82 && fifth >= 78.5) 
      store.add("2.25");
    
else if (fifth < 79 && fifth >= 75.5) 
      store.add("2.50");
    
else if (fifth < 76 && fifth >= 72.5) 
      store.add("2.75");
    
else if (fifth < 73 && fifth >= 69.5) 
      store.add("3.00");
    
else if (fifth < 70 && fifth >= 0) 
      store.add("5.00");
    
else
      store.add("NE");

